# Ошибка "NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID" при попытке перехода по протоколу HTTPS на локальный веб-сайт IIS

Tags: windows, https, iis, localhost, certificate

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: невозможно открыть локальный веб-сайт (localhost) через браузер по HTTPS (TLS). При переходе выдает ошибку:"Подключение не защищено" с пометкой "NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID". Предоставленный сертификат этого сайта соответственно отображается недействительным (хотя это не так).
Мои действия  были следующими:

1. Добавил диспетчер служб IIS на windows 10
2. Т.к. я хочу, чтобы аутентификация сайта происходила по сертификату, выданному внешним центром сертификации (КриптоПро), а не самоподписанным, то я загрузил сертификат CA с сайта и закинул его в "доверенные центры сертификации" в реестр на локальном компьютере.
3. Создал запрос на сертификат в "Сертификаты сервера". Получил по этому запросу сертификат с того СА и установил его через запрос установки.
4. Для своего сайта добавил привязку для HTTPS по 443 порту с выданным ранее сертификатом, добавил IP адрес и имя узла, которое совпадает с URL сайта.
5. Сделал соответствующие записи в hosts, перезапустил сайт и перешел на него. Получил ту же самую ошибку. Примечательно, что с самоподписанными сертификатами все корректно работает.
   Заранее благодарю ответ!

Comment: Сертификат выдается на конкретное доменное имя. Врядли вы получили сертификат на доменное имя `localhost`

Comment: верно, но тогда вылезла бы ошибка несоответствия доменного имени, но была бы возможность все равно зайти на сайт. Хотя в выданном CA сертификате нет графы DNS-имени